# Intuition for Reinhardt domains

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, several-complex-variables

I'm taking a complex analysis course, and in a lecture on several complex variables my professor defined Reinhardt domains in $\mathbb{C}^n$ as domains invariant under the action of the n-dimensional torus. I'd like help to better understand this concept. Some questions:

1. The only examples I can think of are either n-dimensional balls or shells. Are there any other Reinhardt domains?
2. My professor drew a box with the top right corner cut out (in the space of absolute values) and claimed this was also a Reinhardt domain in $\mathbb{C}^2.$ I don't see why that would be: aren't there rotations that would land part of this domain into that corner?
3. I don't yet understand why this would be a useful definition to make. Why is this the right concept for domains for functions of several variables?
   Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean a subspace invariant under the action by $(U(1))^n\subset\Bbb C^n$ right

Comment: @pancini Precisely

Comment: How is a corner removed? Please explain. What about a polydisk like $B(r)\times B(s)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm having to type this on my phone, so I apologize for not wording my question better. In a graph of $|z_1|$ against $|z_2|$, draw a symmetric L-shape, or equivalently a square with the bottom left corner at the origin and a smaller square at the top right corner cut out. Does this define a Reinhardt domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$? I believe my prof claimed it did, but I may be mistaken

Comment: @TedShifrin Your comment prompts another question: what kind of sets could you cut out from the unit square in this "absolute space" and still have a Reinhardt domain? Unless I'm mistaken your polydisk should look like part of an ellipse in this space. Is it a Reinhardt domain? It seems to me you can rotate so that the smaller ball is larger one was, and you have points that were previously in the set that aren't now

Comment: No, the polydisk is a rectangle in your magnitude space, is it not? Remember that your rotations occur coordinate by coordinate, not in the product picture. I haven't thought about Reinhardt domains in about 50 years, so I am rusty.

Comment: @TedShifrin You’re right, of course. Thinking about this example now leads me to think that just about any sort of set in the magnitude space defines a Reinhardt domain, as coordinatewise rotations do not affect the absolute values. Is this correct?

Comment: Yup. Sounds perfectly right to me.

Answer (score 1):

The subclass of complete Reinhardt domains (domains closed under the map $(z_1,\ldots z_n) \mapsto (\lambda_1z_1,\ldots, \lambda_nz_n)$ for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\lambda_i| \leq 1$) are useful for two main reasons, in my opinion.

1. Among the easiest domains to do analysis on are those whose defining functions depend only on the modulus of the variables.  For example the ball given by the defining function $r_1(z) = \sum |z_k|^2 - 1$ or an egg domain like $r_2(z) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} |z_k|^2 + |z_{n + 1}|^2 - 1$ are usually much easier to work with than domains whose defining functions depend on the real part of a variable for instance.  Moreover in two-dimensions they can be somewhat visualized as your professor described.  These domains are complete Reinhardt and thus also Reinhardt.  It is easy to come up with examples of complete Reinhardt domains.   Take a polynomial $p$ in the variables $|z_1|,\ldots, |z_n|$ such that $p(0) = 0$ and then let $r(z) = p(|z_1|,\ldots, |z_n|) - 1$.  Then check to make sure the axioms of a defining function are satisfied.
2. The domain of convergence for power series are complete Reinhardt domains and the pseudoconvex complete Reinhardt domains are those that are logarithmically convex.  You can see Krantz's book, chapter 2, for an in depth discussion on these topics.